# Checkerboard using Shadergraph

Tags: unity, shaders, unity-shader-graph

In Unity Shadergraph, how can I create a checkerboard pattern that works independently of the size of the quad that it is applied to?

Here's what I got so far. Since I have set the Frequency to 10x6, this will work for a quad that has a scale of 20x12. However, if I increase the scale of the quad, the checkerboard will get stretched to fit. But instead, I would like it to "add more squares" to fit the new size.

Is there a way to get it to somehow use the size of the quad instead of manually specifying the frequency?

[image]

Comment: What quads will you be drawing these on? If they're axis-aligned and don't move, you may be able to use worldspace texturing to solve this problem.

Comment: Just one big quad to cover the whole level. Using this as a background for prototyping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pipe a worldspace position value into the checkerboard's UV input, instead of the default texture coordinate:

[image: Position node with space = Absolute World plugged into Checkerboard UV]

This assumes you want your quad to sit in the XY plane. If you want it in XZ, you'll want to swizzle the vector first to move Z into the Y slot.

Here are two ways to do that swizzle:

[image: Swizzling with either a Swizzle Node or a Split and a Vector2]

Comment: Thank you, the first solution (XY plane) works for me. However, I noticed that the resulting checkerboard is offset from my tilegrid by 0.5 on both the x and y axis (even though my quad is positioned at (0,0,0). So I piped the Position output into an Add node, and that result into the UV input of the Checkerboard.